# Getting “Error loading MySQLdb module: No module named MySQLdb” in django-cms

Tags: python, mysql, django, django-cms

I can't connect with mysql and I can't do "python manage.py syncdb" on it

how to connect with mysql in django and django-cms without any error?

Comment: Have you actually installed MySQLdb?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

## to connect to mysql with django

```
sudo apt-get install git          # to install git

sudo apt-get install python-pip   # to install pip

sudo pip install Django           # to install Django to your system
```

After that you **should go to project path and then execute** the following command, the same path of 'manage.py' file

```
pip install mysql-python
```

Finally you may synchronous your database without problem

```
python manage.py syncdb
```

Answer (score 3):

This is an error message you get if MySQLdb isn't installed on your computer.

The easiest way to install it would be by entering `pip install MySQL-python` into your command line.