# How To Install Django CMS with MySQL

Tags: django, django-cms

can someone explain me how to install django cms with mySQL , I follwed instructions  from

https://github.com/divio/django-cms-tutorial/blob/master/Step%201%20-%20Initial%20Setup.md

and sucessfully installed django-cms with sqllite3, but when I tried with mySQL I get errors.

Django CMS installation process asks:

> **Database configuration** (in URL format) [default sqlite://localhost/project.db]:  if I press enter it will install it with sqlite , what I need to type to install it with MySQL

I tried `mysql://localhost/django_db`

but it won't work..

Answer (score 3):

When I got to that part of the installer, I used this style of connection string and it worked for me:

```
mysql://username:password@hostname/schema_name
```

Comment: Do you have to keep your password in quotes? this isn't working for me but I can connect to mysql no problem

Comment: @DanielTate The password can't contain spaces and probably other characters too. Sorry this is over a year old. I didn't want to answer unless I tested it myself first and I just got around to playing with it. I tried to use the password "super duper awesome" and no matter how I tried it, backslashes to escape, quotes around the password, etc, it always failed. My best advice is to set the password on your MySQL server to a password the DjangoCMS wizard can accept, then change it on the server and in the DATABASES dictionary in the settings.py file located in your app package.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem and used @Tarek Kalaji's approach.

My configuration:
host Ubuntu 18.04,
pip 19.2.3,
djangocms-installer 1.2.0rc1,
djangocms 3.6,
django 2.1

I first installed djangocms via the installer using the default database settings as all other attempts at mysql failed at this point.

Then I edited the settings.py just as was advised, replacing the sqlite settings with those:

```
DATABASES = {
    'default':
        {
            'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql',
            'NAME': 'mytestdb',
            'HOST': 'localhost', 
            'USER': 'root', 
            'PASSWORD': 'mysqlpassword', 
            'PORT': ''
        }
}
```

I actually use a mysql server in a virtual machine in which I created a new empty database (e.g. mytestdb).

Changing the 'DATABASES' setting had failed for me before. I think because I had already migrated content into the sqlite database. I would advise to set up the mysql database right at the beginning before any 'python manage.py migrate' call. I would guess, off course, that the content can also be shifted using database dumps but I have no experience migrating data from sqlite to mysql (or any other SQL).

The following steps in my case, however, are much more simple. They are basically just what you need for any django mysql use case.

```
pip install mysqlclient
```

and

```
pythong manage.py migrate
```

That was it.

It too me quite some time to figure this out. Therefore I think it's a good idea to make a new post.

Answer (score 0):

you can install it with sqllite with default, and create empty database with example name 'mytestdb', after installation you may change settings.py directly

```
DATABASES = {
    'default':
        {
            'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql', #.sqlite3
            'NAME': 'mytestdb',
            'HOST': 'localhost', 
            'USER': 'root', 
            'PASSWORD': 'mysqlpassword', 
            'PORT': ''
        }
}
```

to connect to mysql with django

```
sudo apt-get install git          # to install git

sudo apt-get install python-pip   # to install pip

sudo pip install Django           # to install Django to your system
```

After that you should go to project path and then execute the following command, the same path of 'manage.py' file

```
pip install mysql-python
```

Finally you may synchronous your database without problem

```
python manage.py syncdb
```

this is the same problem [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24380269/getting-error-loading-mysqldb-module-no-module-named-mysqldb-in-django-cms) I hope it be helpful ...

Answer (score 0):

Nothing worked for me until I followed the Djangocms installation by hand prescription, which is found here:

[Manual installation of djangocms](http://docs.django-cms.org/en/latest/how_to/install.html)

It worked for me, just follow all of the steps.